# SQL Report Builder how to write or link parameter to SQL table value in easy way

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, builder

I want to make I/O field into my report so I can set and read parameter from SQL table. I already have SQL table with systemparameters and working report, I'd just want to find easiest possible way to edit parameter from report page.

Comment: just to be clear you wish to have a parameter on Report for ex: Created on Date as parameter and by giving input as date you will filter your data coming from your dataset?

Comment: I can add parameters for filtering data if I just input it manually, but report does not remember what I typed in parameter box last time. Also old report takes parameter value from dataset value that is from SQL table, so I'd rather just change old  SQL table value. So my problem is that I do not know how to edit old values in SQL table from report. Of course I can change it with SQL manager or whatsoever but report user cannot do that.

Comment: Alright, so you already have a parameter for your report and this parameter does takes value from sql table. For sake of explanation let’s say you have a parameter date and this parameter takes value fro sql table column “created on date”. Now you wish to change value for this parameter from sql table  and it should not be created on date but modified on date. Do I understand it correctly or I am still missing something??

Comment: It would be better to think like if I had a table with columns name and age. I will get some particular name and take age as parameter for report. Now my report would show all names with this same age. If I change age parameter it would save age into sql table on this particular name. So first I'd have name=Bob, age=50 then I load report and change parameter age from 50 to 55 then I have name=Bob, age=55 next time until I change the parameter. However I cannot figure out how to change age from report parameter field so it also changes same field in sql table.